# ¿Almacenar Notificación Push Firebase?

Tags: base-de-datos, firebase, real-time

Al enviar un mensaje Push con Firebase FCM, es posible guardar ese mensaje en la base de datos de Firebase ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Por el momento no es posible interceptar las notificaciones antes de que salgan de firebase ( a menos que las estés enviando desde tu propio servidor).

En tu situación lo ideal sería usar el servicio que recibe los mensajes,
 en el caso de Android `FirebaseMessagingService.onMessageReceived` y en el caso de iOS en tu `AppDelegate application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:` para interceptar los mensajes y además de mostrar la notificación hacer el upload a la base de Firebase.